# .htaccess redirect except for specific subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all requests to website.ext to website2.ext except if someone goes to website.ext/specific_dir (or something "under" the specific dir, suc as website.ext/specific_dir/controller/action)

How would I accomplish such a thing in .htaccess?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this pretty easily using `mod_rewrite`...

I'm assuming that you want to keep the same URI and just change the domain name. I.e.

```
GOOD: http://example.com/dir/file > http://example2.com/dir/file
BAD : http://example.com/dir/file > http://example2.com/
```

## Solution

Add the following `.htaccess` rules to the base directory of the first website (modified accordingly)...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/GOOD_DIR
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1
```

You may also want to add some flags:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/GOOD_DIR [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/$1 [R=301,END]
```

#### Example redirects

The above rules will redirect the following:

```
http://exmaple.com/index.php             > http://example2.com/index.php
http://exmaple.com/file.html             > http://example2.com/file.html
http://exmaple.com/about/membership.php  > http://example2.com/about/membership.php
http://exmaple.com/code/layout.css       > http://example2.com/code/layout.css
http://exmaple.com/images/goofy.png      > http://example2.com/images/goofy.png
```

But won't redirect:

```
 http://example.com/GOOD_DIR
 http://example.com/good_dir
 http://example.com/GooD_DIr
 http://example.com/good_dir/file.html
 http://example.com/good_dir/sub_dir/other_file.php
```

#### Quirks

The above rules are simple and probably good enough. However, they do come with some quriks...

Some quirks which won't be redirected:

```
http://example.com/good_dir.html < If a file has the same name as the dir
http://example.com/good_dir_2    < If a directory has the same start to the name
```

To fix this behaviour you can update the regex pattern to be more specific:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/GOOD_DIR(/.*)?$
```

With `NC` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/GOOD_DIR(/.*)?$ [NC]
```

#### Flags Explanation

The `NC` flag specifies that the regex pattern is **not** case sensitive; in other words `a-z` is treated the same as  `A-Z` (e.g. neither `good_dir` or `GOOD_DIR` will be redirected).

The `R` flag specifies that a redirect should be sent to the browser. The `=301` specifies the status code to be given as the reason, for example:

- `301` permanently moved;
- `302` unspecified reason;
- `307` temporary redirect

---

### More information

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

Got the following which is not perfectly precise but works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub-dir.*
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newsite.ext/ [R=301,L]
```